# TeXstudio add new Thesaurus

Tags: texstudio

I just installed TeXStudio because I think it has more features than TeXmaker.

One thing I can't get to work is the thesaurus. I have [downloaded and installed a Danish thesaurus from LibreOffice](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/stavekontrolden-danish-dictionary/pscreleasefolder.2011-09-30.0280139318/2.1/dict-da-2.1.oxt), however it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong? Is that `.dat` file broken?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) You probably have use for the answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87652/19384 Although it primarily concerns spelling, installation of thesaurus files follow the same principles.

Comment: I have downloaded the Danish spell dict, and it works without any problems. It's only the thesaurus that dosen't work. Have tried the one from openoffice aswell. So no that's not how to fix the problem.

Comment: @PeterJansson I have to agree, I couldn’t get the danish thesaurus (`th_da_DK.dat`) to work either. The Thesaurus Window doesn’t show any entries and all buttons don’t have any effect. @DavidJunker Have you considered posting a bug report at the [Tracker of TeXstudio](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/)? I suspect a faulty `.dat` file, too; although it looks very similar compared to working ones.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to deal with a bug in TeXstudio.