# How to add dictionary in texstudio?

Tags: texstudio, spelling

I am newbie to both latex and Ubuntu-linux 14.04.
I already installed texlive and texstudio for latex environment. Everything works fine.

When I am trying to use spell check option it is giving error as "no dictionary available ". So always my document is having spelling mistakes.

Please help me with this. What packages have to install to get English dictionary. With spell check automatically.

Comment: Did you try this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87650/dictionary-for-texstudio-no-dictionary-available

Answer (score 14):

Basically, you have to download the dictionary from [OpenOffice website](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/english-dictionaries-apache-openoffice), uncompress the `.oxt` file using 7zip (or change the extension to `.zip` and uncompress it), and copying the `.aff` and `.dic` file to a folder (I recommend to create a folder on dropbox so you can reference that folder from any computer that you are using) that you will later you should set up on the Texstudio application.

You can find a far better explanation on "*Dictionary for TeXstudio: “No dictionary Available”* " (see @Sid comment) or [here](http://www.rohitfarmer.in/computing/linux-and-open-source/how-to-make-dictionary-work-in-texstudio/)

Comment: Then this question can be closed as a duplicate of [Dictionary for TeXstudio: “No dictionary Available”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87650/5764)...

Comment: Yes, but my reputation do not let me to add comments, or flagging the question as a duplicate.  If you can do it. Please do so.  :)