# TeXstudio: “No dictionary Available”, although it is!

Tags: texstudio, dictionaries

I have the same issue as this person: [Dictionary for TeXstudio: “No dictionary Available”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87650/dictionary-for-texstudio-no-dictionary-available)
with the exception, that I have the dictionaries. I also downloaded some, only to check if mine don't work. But it seems to be an issue of TeXstudio, because it finds the dictionaries when I give it the right path (under Options>Configure TexStudio>General>Dictionary), but when I click check spelling it's still complaining, that there is no dictionary available. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong or how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Do the dictionaries show up in the selection box "Default Dictionary" right below the setting where you specified your path? If not they are not loaded (probably because they are not valid).

The dictionaries are hunspell dictionaries consisting of two files: `.dic` and `.aff`. Both need to be present. If you use the dictionaries provided in `.oxt` files, you need to import them using the button in the options (or extract the `.oxt` files manually, which are just renamed zip files).

Comment: This is what I meant with TeXstudio 'finds them', it shows me the dictionaries in the "Default Dictionary". Not only the once which were pre installed, also the once which I installed (and unpacked) myself. So they are there, in the right format, and they work for everything else except for TeXstudio. Maybe I shuold just try to reinstall TeXstudio?

Comment: No, re-installation didn't help. I also discovered, that I can't make any updates, because TeXstudio tells me, that the connection is closed. This is getting more and more weird.

Comment: Which version of TXS are you using?

Comment: TeXstudio 2.6.6 (hg 4099)
Using Qt Version 4.8.6, compiled with Qt 4.8.4 D

Comment: That's quite outdated. Can you please try the current 2.8.6?

Comment: Was having the same problem with a new version of TexStudio. Reverting settings to defaults fixed the problem.