# Working with several dictionaries problem - TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, dictionaries

As suggested in [Dictionary for TeXstudio: “No dictionary Available”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87650/dictionary-for-texstudio-no-dictionary-available), I have downloaded the dictionaries that I want. I can see that TexStudio is recognizing them, from the Options --> Configure TexStudio --> Default Language, where both of my wanted languages are successfully showing. The thing is that I can decide only one of them and I cannot make them both work.

How can I make them work together (Greek and English dictionary) without switching manually every time?

Answer (score 5):

You can only use one dictionary at a time.

However, it is possible to merge two dictionaries to create a hybrid dictionary matching both languages. See e.g. http://code.google.com/p/hunspell-merge/

Comment: can you provide steps on how to merge the dictionaries and insert them, since I checked hunspell but I couldn't set it to work.