# TexStudio - Getting list of bad words to work

Tags: texstudio, spelling

Using TexStudio 2.10.8 on MacOSX 10.11.3 with language-tool installed.

I am trying to get the "bad words" highlighting of TexStudio to work. Therefore I created a list of bad-words `badwords/bad_words.tex`, with one word per line (line separated).

bad_words.txt contents:

```
also
eigentlich
sprich
...
```

I setup TexStudio to look in the folder `badwords`: [image: TexStudio settings snippet with "Check for Bad Words" enabled and path set up]

TexStudio should recognize `eigentlich`, `also` and `super` from my `bad_words.tex` list, but it does not recognize any of the bad words used in this sentence:[image: Sentence containing three words from my list of bad-words]

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get a solution for the bad words checking? Because a new user (albflo) of this page is stuck with the same problem! The bad words work perfectly for myself with TeXstudio 2.11.0 on Win7. Maybe it is just linked to MacOSX?

Comment: Actually I have not checked this for a while. Will do so, when I get back to the macos workstation next week.

Answer (score 3):

TeXstudio should provide you already with a file called

```
de.badWords
```

which should have been installed to a subfolder.

```
utilities/de.badWords
```

Otherwise: goto

```
Applications/TeXstudio/<right click and> Show Package Contents
```

and see if the file is installed in one of the subfolders.

or perform:

```
locate de.badWords
```

in a Terminal

You might also see this for additional clues:

[Dictionary for TeXstudio: “No dictionary Available”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87650/dictionary-for-texstudio-no-dictionary-available)

Comment: I looked for the included badWords files and found them, but I still get no highlighting. I then double checked that "check for bad words" is activated and that the highlighting is set up accordingly. Btw. does it work on your system?

Comment: @FlorianZ.: I try to avoid so called "Weichspülerworte" (bad words) therefore I have no clue if it works on my system. The checkbox is activated though.

Comment: In `syntaxhighlighting` section in the config-menu bad words are supposed to marked `stricken` in some purple color. But that seem to have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

The bad words file must be named after the current language/dictionary. If you use "de_DE" then use "de_DE.badWords"

For me I had "de_DE_frami" so it did not pick up the "de_DE.badWords"