# Which file extensions shall I include when I install a new dictionary?

Tags: texstudio, spelling, dictionaries

I am installing a new dictionary (*) in TeXstudio and I am following the instructions provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87652/98306). I have opted to install the new dictionary inside the TeXstudio dictionaries folder: `..\TeXstudio\dictionaries`.

As far as I understand, dictionaries use the extensions `.dic`, `.aff`, `.dat`, `.stopWords` and `.badWords`. I have also seen the `.level2` extension.

However, when I open the folder of the new dictionary, I find some other new extensions besides the aforementioned, such as `.xml`, `.xcu` and `.idx`, as you can see in the following image:

[image: different extensions]

I have no problem with the `.txt` files, since I know that they are readme and license files, so not adding them inside the dictionaries folder will have no harmful effects. But I don't know if I should include the `.xml`, `.xcu` and `.idx` files.

- **Why are all these different extensions used in the dictionaries?**
- **Which file extensions shall I include when I install a new dictionary, so that it works properly?**
- **Which file extensions shall I not include?**

(*): [Catalan dictionary pack (spell checker, hyphenation patterns, and thesaurus)](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/catalan-dictionary-pack-spell-checker-hyphenation-patterns-and-thesaurus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the answer you linked to is partly obsolete. It's still working, but TeXstudio can do most of the steps for you. Simply click "Import Dictionary" in the options and select the desired `.oxt` file.

[image]

But to answer your questions:

1. TeXstudio uses Hunspell dictionaries (as do OpenOffice and LibreOffice). These are the `.dic` and `.aff` files. Additionally it can use thesaurus data `.dat` and has proprietary `.badWords` and `.stopWords` files.
2. The easiest way to obtain dictionaries is to load the dictionaries from OpenOffice / LibreOffice plugins `.oxt`, which is actually a zipped folder containing the data. These plugins contain some additional data like readme, licences and hyphenation. You can leave or remove these additional files as you want. TeXstudio currently ignores them. For simplicity and to be on the safe side with licences, the "Import Dictionary" just keeps all files present in the `.oxt` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim! That's a very nice feature of TeXstudio, it makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, i would download and "Import" the `.oxt` files but still the new dictionary won't show up in the choice box.

I then navigated to my `C:\User\MyUserFolder\AppData\Roaming\TeXstudio\dictionaries` folder in Windows and found out that the "Import dictionary" button only unzipped the `.oxt` archive inside the /dictionaries folder; what i needed to do was to copypaste the `.aff`, `.dic`, `.ign` files i needed into the `\dictionaries` folder to let TeXstudio find the new dictionary.

I did not try that, but (my guess) also adding the full path to the unzipped folder in the `Spelling Dictionary Directories` textbox should work.