# How to add an Italian dictionary for spell checking in TeXstudio?

Tags: dictionaries

Does anybody know a simple fast and safe method to add an Italian dictionary to TeXstudio? I've been looking for solution for hours, downloaded MBs of useless files and still I can't find it.

Comment: have you tried the instructions in this question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87650/dictionary-for-texstudio-no-dictionary-available

Comment: Still unable to find the right file.

Comment: try version 4.2 Italian dictionary for LibreOffice (here: http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/italian-dictionary-thesaurus-hyphenation-patterns/releases/4.2). you can use it as well for OO. to install follow steps in question linked in previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Italian dictionary version 4.2 from http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/italian-dictionary-thesaurus-hyphenation-patterns/releases/4.2

as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87652/100482