# How can I set Catalan as the language to revise in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio, languages

TeXstudio itself doesn't have Catalan, so I tried LanguageTool in TeXstudio, but I can't make it revise Catalan even though TeXstudio has Catalan. Could you please tell me how can I make TeXstudio revise my text in Catalan?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87650/dictionary-for-texstudio-no-dictionary-available

Comment: Thank you so much! I had downloaded the dictionary by myself but hadn't worked. Now I know that I have to change it to .zip and unzip it. It worked. Thank you!

Comment: De res `@SerMarFe`!