# TexStudio list all misspelled words

Tags: texstudio, spelling

Is it possible to get a list of all words, that are marked red because it was not found in the dictionary, so i can see in a huge document where there are still words, which have to be checked.

Comment: You might consider changing your title to "TexStudio list all misspelled words", since "red warnings" might be confused for issues in the log file. Unfortunately, I don't believe such a feature exists. You could submit a request [here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the toolbar, you can go to Tools > Check Spelling... or use the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+; to cycle through the misspellings. I am not aware of any way to export this list to a text file, if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: You'd need to load a dictionary, first. Go to Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Language Checking; there are links in there to download dictionaries from OpenOffice and LibreOffice. See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87650/dictionary-for-texstudio-no-dictionary-available).