# Spell checking within function arguments

Tags: spelling

I am currently writing my resume in texStudio using a template that uses `\cvitem`. The issue I'm having is the spell check does not check the spelling within the arguments for `\cvitem`. For example, if I want to add a section called "Topic" and include the description "Item" I would use, `\cvitem{Topic}{Item}`. If I have a spelling error and enter `\cvitem{Tpic}{Itm}` instead, spell check will not catch the spelling errors of "Topic" or "Item". However, if these spelling errors are outside the argument, in a free standing paragraph, they will be caught. For a dictionary I am using the English dictionary as provided by Open Office.

Is there a way to turn on spell checking inside arguments?

Here is an example of TexStudio missing an spelling error. As you can see the issue is caught when the text is outside an argument.

[image: Missed Spelling Errors]

This is a screen shot of the currently used Language settings.

[image: Current language settings]

Comment: Hi @BobJoe1803 and welcome to TeX-SE. Could you please add a MWE (Minimal Working Example)? When TeXStudio checks spelling, it depends of the language and dictionaries the user has set and installed.  On the other hand, I don't know which language `Tpic` and `Itm` belong to. Are you reffering to the words themselves or to the syntax highlight around the command `\cvitem`? Syntax highlights depend of `.cwl` files.

Comment: I updated the question and I hope the updates make the issue clearer.

Comment: Strange, if you are using `hunspell` from Libre Office, it is able to differentiate in TeX syntax. Can you test with different editor (Emacs, vim?)

Comment: That's strange @BobJoe1803, could you add a screen shot of TeXStudio showing the "non spell checking" in your machine (I'm on Windows, are you on Linux?). I got [this template](https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-cv-and-cover-letter-2015-version/sttkgjcysttn) to `moderncv` class and my TeXStudio shows any spell error. Actually it shows erros inside any command for any selected language. Could you also post a picture of your Options -> Configura TeXstudio -> `Language Checking` configurations?

Comment: @FHZ I am using Linux and I believe that is the same template that I am using. I've added some screen shots, hopefully they are helpful.

Comment: From your print, I noticed there is no path in `Theaaurus Database` and `Wordlist Directory`. I'm not sure if this might cause some interference. Check the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87650/dictionary-for-texstudio-no-dictionary-available) if some might fix the issue. There is [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/thread/e5f2ba3c/) at TeXstudio Forum about issues with Dictionary which might have some suggestion for you. I could not reproduce your issue, therefore there is not much I can help. Sorry.

Comment: Another less likely possibility is some "non default" configuration at Options -> Configure TexStudio -> `Syntax Highlighting`. Verify the `Wave underline` column. It should be marked at some "missings" at `LaTeX checking` and `Language checking`. But I don't see any relation between any `Wave underline` option and your issue. I use the default settings there and my TeXstudio checks the spelling erros inside commands.

Comment: Have you tried this syntax "`\cvitem{ Tpic }`" using spaces before and after braces? Same for "`\textbf{ Tpic }`". This could be related to a false recognition of braces.

Comment: I've been through and checked those issues with no improvements. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling with no change. I think I'll just have to change to Texmaker instead. Thanks for the ideas though.